# Create kinect skeleton for comparison

Tags: kinect

I'm going build an application where the user is supposed to try to mimic a static pose of a person on a picture. So I'm thinking that a Kinect is the most suitable way to get the information about the users pose.

I have found answers here on Stackoverflow suggesting that the comparison of the two skeletons (the skeleton defining the pose on the picture and the skeleton of the user) is best done by comparing the joint angles etc. I was thinking that there already would be some functionality for comparing poses of skeletons in the SDK but haven't found any information saying otherwise.

One thing makes me very unsure:
**Is it possible to manually define a skeleton so I can make the static pose from the picture somehow? Or do I need to record it with help of Kinect Studio? I would really prefer some tool for creating the poses by hand...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for users to pose and get recognized for the correct pose made by the user. Then you can follow these few steps to have it implemented in c#.

You can refer to the sample project `Controls Basics-WPF` provided by microsoft in the SDK Browser v2.0( Kinect for Windows)

Steps:

1. Record in Kinect studio 2 the position you want the pose to be.
2. open up Visual gesture builder to train your clips( selection of the clip that is correct)
3. build the vgbsln in the visual gesture builder to produce a gbd file( this will be imported into your project as the file that the `gesturedetector.cs` will read and implement into your project.
4. code out your own logic on what will happen when user have matching poses in the `gestureresultview.cs`.

Start off with one and slowly make the files into an array to loop when you have multiple poses.

I would prefer this way instead of coding out the exact skeleton joints of the poses.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! I need to test Kinect Studio 2 a more since I need to match the pose to a picture. Maybe possible to add the picture as background to have something to compare to when recording the pose?

Comment: yes it is possible to do that in wpf, if you find the solution useful, hope i can get an upvote XP

Comment: When you say it is possible to do it in wpf. Then you mean that I need to make a application for recording the pose that is supposed to be used as comparison in the real application?

Comment: Yes. For example, you make the application to detect if the person is sitting or standing just by looking at the skeleton joints. Same applies to raising your hand up and they can detect that u have raised your hand. all these will be checked against the database gbd file you inputted into the program to assist them in matching the same position.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure about the best way to generate the target skeletons that I think you mean should be in the databse gdb file. I need to some way to create target skeletons which the users skeleton can be matched to. The target skeletons should have the same poses as figures on different pictures. So I also need to create the program for generating the target skeleton that can display the image and record the skeleton at the same time. I mean, there are no tools available for this? Maybe I'm not explaining myself so well  here. :)

Comment: Between coding out the skeleton and using visual gesture builder. Using visual gesture builder would be more appropriate if your poses are complex.  If the poses are simple, it would be faster to be done on code. Accuracy wise, visual gesture builder would be more accurate.  "The target skeletons should have the same poses as figures on different pictures." - this can be done in both ways, but i recommend visual gesture builder if you want more accurate and complex poses

Comment: Im not sure wad tools you are looking for, but with the gbd files of the poses, you are already able to achieve what you need. In addition of coding out the logic

Comment: I found this which seems good. Adding the link here if someone else is as confused as me. :) Thank you for your help! https://vitruviuskinect.com/

Comment: Oh if you are using vitruvius i have a guide on setting it up on visual studio on my github

Comment: That would be a great help

Comment: https://bingcheng45.wordpress.com/2017/05/05/step-by-step-kinect-swipe-gesture-tutorial/

Here is the blog i made with the pdf containing the guide

Comment: That was really helpful!